# How Can i use DocuSign in Laravel 6.*

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to use DocuSign for the first time and followed [this documentation](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/Laravel-Docusign). I have installed it in laravel 6 and my requirement is to generate a pdf file in my code on button click then it will docusign Auth user then it will be send to signer and he will sign it by docusign it. But i am not able to understand its because no enough info provided.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an official DocuSign code wrapper and you will need to contact them directly for support. You can download and try our official DocuSign [code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php) . DS library installation is covered in the readme file and you can use the same approach to install and use it in Laravel. The code example contains over 30 different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

A new PHP SDK Supporting Laravel is in progress and should be released soon.
The one you mentioned was built by [Eric Tucker](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developer-spotlight-eric-tucker-documate) and you an ask him about it on the GitHub pages.

I'll update this answer when we have the new PHP SDK.